flutter http post in ios not receiveing any response
I am working on my first app and I was working on Android I made all configurations for Android and all HTTP requests to the backend works fine and I uploaded to the backend on the server called contaboserver.
But when I started to run the app in an ios emulator and iPhone real devices like iPhone 7 plus, iPhone 13 and iPhone 14 I received all the get request fine but when I make post requests it seems not excited or send it at all I don't receive any response but in Android, it works fine I tried with HTTP package and don't work and I tried it with dio and still don't work.
I also tried with my local host and the server I tried with and without jsonEncode.
After awhile I realize that the code is working or I receive response but after 15 to 20 minute when I remove timeout()
This is my code with both dio and http:
update:
i relize the image i converted to base64 Cause this problem
whene i remove the image i get response fast i dont know why its happen in ios only in macos i use Version 14.5 Beta sonoma in vmware
    singUp(String userName, String phone, String image, String locationId,
    String subLocation) async {
  var myToken = OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.id;
  await clearLoginInfo();
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);

  try {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    };
    var list = {
      'u_name': userName,
      'u_phone': phone.toString(),
      'u_image': image,
      'u_location': subLocation.toString(),
      'u_date': formattedDate.toString(),
      'u_descrption': 'u_descrption',
      'notification_token': myToken.toString()
    };
    final dio = Dio();
    final response = await dio.post(
      'http://10.0.0.2/kolshy/user_sigup.php',

      data: list,
    ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
    print(response.data);

    // final response = await http.post(
    //   Uri.parse('http://10.0.0.2/kolshy/user_sigup.php'),
    //   body: {
    //     'u_name': userName,
    //     'u_phone': phone.toString(),
    //     'u_image': image,
    //     'u_location': subLocation.toString(),
    //     'u_date': formattedDate.toString(),
    //     'u_descrption': 'u_descrption',
    //     'notification_token': myToken.toString()
    //   },
    // ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
    // print('===========================================${response.body}');
    // print('===========================================${response.statusCode}');

    // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //   final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    //   if (data['message'] == '1') {
    //     await loginByPhone(phone);
    //     return 1;
    //   } else if (data['message'] == '2') {
    //     // phone Exist
    //     return 2;
    //   } else if (data['message'] == '3') {
    //     // name Exist
    //     return 3;
    //   }
    // }
  } on TimeoutException {
    return 5;
  } on SocketException {
    return 4;
  }
}    


update : the problem has been fixed
the issue was becuse the image size
The image size is large on the iPhone, and this is the reason for the delay in the response from the server
The problem was solved by using the flutter_image_compress package

the problem has been fixed
